# How to send commands to putty

Tags: putty

I'm writing a simple executable in C that needs to open a putty session and send commands to it, then close putty.  I can open/close the putty session (i'm not that bad) but i'm not too sure on how to send putty the commands.

Any ideas??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956954/how-to-get-input-from-putty-to-java/28957086#28957086

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817771/java-and-putty-send-commands

Answer (score 3):

From the [PuTTY FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-ipc):

> How can I use PuTTY to make an SSH
>   connection from within another
>   program?
>
> Probably your best bet is to use
>   Plink, the command-line connection
>   tool. If you can start Plink as a
>   second Windows process, and arrange
>   for your primary process to be able to
>   send data to the Plink process, and
>   receive data from it, through pipes,
>   then you should be able to make SSH
>   connections from your program.
>
> This is what CVS for Windows does, for
>   example.

Plink can use PuTTY's saved sessions in addition to opening sites directly.

PLink's options are documented in [Chapter 7](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) of the PuTTY manual.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DLL, Luke. http://www.winputty.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the source for [QuickPutty](http://www.deckmyn.org/olivier/software)?  It's LGPL licensed.

Comment: But what IS it? The link provides no information about what it does. Just a half-dozen download links.

Comment: it's a quick-start front-end to PuTTY, which provides a desktop window with links to each defined PuTTY profile.  If the OP actually wants to send I/O to an SSH shell started via PuTTY it's probably not that useful.