# How to get input from Putty to Java?

Tags: java, ubuntu, putty

I am quite new to Ubuntu and shell programming. I am using putty to execute `vmstat` and `iostat` commands on Ubuntu. I need to execute those commands in java (Windows environment) and get an `InputStream` of the result. Is it possible?

Comment: try using jsch and a shell channel

Comment: Not via putty, no. You'll need to use a library to connect via SSH to the machine. Also, not sure but you should check whether these commands expect a terminal; my guess is that they do, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I've had success with Jsch, but I suggest making sure your understanding of streams is solid before doing any networking applications.

Comment: You can use Runtime class to execute any native code (i.e command line commands) in java and parse the input/output stream. However, as suggested above, using a java library would be better to open an ssh connection and parsing it;s output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use [`plink`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (a command-line interface to the PuTTY back end).

[For example](https://superuser.com/a/130528),

`plink remote_host "ls -l"`

I've successfully used this to, from a Windows-based TFS Build, execute an Android build on a Linux box. So it's possible to work with the output from plink programatically.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157429/3063884) of how to call a shell command from within Java.