# Execute command line in PuTTY with java

Tags: java, ssh, command-line, putty

So I am writing a program in java that launches PuTTY from the command line and then I need to be able to switch over to the PuTTY command line once it opens instead of my windows command line. How do I make that switch so I can continues to enter commands in PuTTY?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603187/how-to-send-commands-to-putty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send commands to putty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603187/how-to-send-commands-to-putty)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to look into the  [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

The easy part is to use that to start putty. And when you are lucky, you can connect (pipe) the input/output streams into/from that process.

In other words: you will have to wire the parent process; and the child process using those streams; and then you *might* be able to read all output created by putty and write stuff there.

But that would require that putty prints the "connection" output into its stdout stream; something I very much doubt.